# Are the conversations monitored/stored when using dialogflow for fulfillment

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

We are building a Chat/Voice Bot using the below flow at a high level.

Mobile Device => Google Actions => Google Dialogflow => WebHook Fulfillment using an API => Response to Dialogflow => Response to Mobile Device.

We have a requirement to clear Security assessment from our enterprise while exposing data into public domain.

1. Does google store the conversations made via dialogflow anywhere?
2. Does google as part of its monitoring hear the conversations for betterment of its product ?

In the terms, there is a mention that Google does monitor the APIs but it is not clear on the extent of monitoring.

Any help to collate information on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find logging settings in Dialogflow agent settings (cog icon next to agent name) in General tab. "Log settings" is the last section. If it is enabled, you can find logs in agent History and Stackdriver (but this is disabled by default).
It doesn't matter if you are using fulfillment or not.

As to listening to conversations when using Google Assistant, ASR is done on Google servers, but recordings are not stored by default unless user will opt in for this option